# Find city names within affiliations and add them with their corresponding countries in new columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, text-mining, country, city

I have a dataframe ‘dfa’ of affiliations that contains city names, for which the country is sometimes missing, e.g. like rows 4 (BAGHDAD) and 7 (BERLIN):

```
dfa <- data.frame(affiliation=c("DEPARTMENT OF PHARMACY, AMSTERDAM UNIVERSITY, AMSTERDAM, THE NETHERLANDS",
                                "DEPARTMENT OF BIOCHEMISTRY, LADY HARDINGE MEDICAL COLLEGE, NEW DELHI, INDIA.",
                                "DEPARTMENT OF PATHOLOGY, CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL, LOS ANGELES, UNITED STATES",
                                "COLLEGE OF EDUCATION FOR PURE SCIENCE, UNIVERSITY OF BAGHDAD.",
                                "DEPARTMENT OF CLINICAL LABORATORY, BEIJING GENERAL HOSPITAL, BEIJING, CHINA.",
                                "LABORATORY OF MOLECULAR BIOLOGY, ISTITUTO ORTOPEDICO, MILAN, ITALY.",
                                "DEPARTMENT OF AGRICULTURE, BERLIN INSTITUTE OF HEALTH, BERLIN",
                                "INSTITUTE OF LABORATORY MEDICINE, UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL, MUNICH, GERMANY.",
                                "DEPARTMENT OF CLINICAL PATHOLOGY, MAHIDOL UNIVERSITY, BANGKOK, THAILAND.",
                                "DEPARTMENT OF BIOLOGY, WASEDA UNIVERSITY, TOKYO, JAPAN",
                                "DEPARTMENT OF MOLECULAR BIOLOGY, MINISTRY OF HEALTH, TEHRAN, IRAN.",
                                "LABORATORY OF CARDIOVASCULAR DISEASE, FUWAI HOSPITAL, BEIJING, CHINA."))
```

I have now a second dataframe ‘dfb’ that contains a list of cities and corresponding country, some of which are present in 'dfa':

```
dfb <- data.frame(city=c("AGRI","AMSTERDAM","ATHENS","AUCKLAND","BUENOS AIRES","BEIJING","BAGHDAD","BANGKOK","BERLIN","BUDAPEST"),
                  country=c("TURKEY","NETHERLANDS","GREECE","NEW ZEALAND","ARGENTINA","CHINA","IRAQ","THAILAND","GERMANY","HUNGARY"))
```

How can I add cities and corresponding countries in two new columns only for cities that are present in both ‘dfa’ and ‘dfb’ (and even when the country is missing, as for BAGHDAD and BERLIN)?

NB: the goal is to add **full** city names but **not part** of them. Below in row 7, an example of what is not wanted: the AGRI city of TURKEY is inappropriately associated with BERLIN because this row includes the 'AGRICULTURE' word.

Is there a simple way to do that, ideally using dplyr?

```
    affiliation      city     country
1      DEPARTMENT OF PHARMACY, AMSTERDAM UNIVERSITY, AMSTERDAM, THE NETHERLANDS AMSTERDAM NETHERLANDS
2  DEPARTMENT OF BIOCHEMISTRY, LADY HARDINGE MEDICAL COLLEGE, NEW DELHI, INDIA.      <NA>        <NA>
3      DEPARTMENT OF PATHOLOGY, CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL, LOS ANGELES, UNITED STATES      <NA>        <NA>
4                 COLLEGE OF EDUCATION FOR PURE SCIENCE, UNIVERSITY OF BAGHDAD.   BAGHDAD        IRAQ
5  DEPARTMENT OF CLINICAL LABORATORY, BEIJING GENERAL HOSPITAL, BEIJING, CHINA.   BEIJING       CHINA
6           LABORATORY OF MOLECULAR BIOLOGY, ISTITUTO ORTOPEDICO, MILAN, ITALY.      <NA>        <NA>
7                 DEPARTMENT OF AGRICULTURE, BERLIN INSTITUTE OF HEALTH, BERLIN      AGRI      TURKEY
8       INSTITUTE OF LABORATORY MEDICINE, UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL, MUNICH, GERMANY.      <NA>        <NA>
9      DEPARTMENT OF CLINICAL PATHOLOGY, MAHIDOL UNIVERSITY, BANGKOK, THAILAND.   BANGKOK    THAILAND
10                       DEPARTMENT OF BIOLOGY, WASEDA UNIVERSITY, TOKYO, JAPAN      <NA>        <NA>
11           DEPARTMENT OF MOLECULAR BIOLOGY, MINISTRY OF HEALTH, TEHRAN, IRAN.      <NA>        <NA>
12        LABORATORY OF CARDIOVASCULAR DISEASE, FUWAI HOSPITAL, BEIJING, CHINA.   BEIJING       CHINA
```

Comment: I want to help ypu but it is too much work to create the dataset. Please copy an paste the frist 10 rows from both datasets as text

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Indeed, here is code. Thanks Samuel and Ronak for your advices.

Comment: demon, if an answer provided solved your problem, could you consider designating it as the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach accounts for the possibility that an affiliation could match more than one city name.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfa %>% 
  mutate(city = map(affiliation, ~ str_extract(.x, dfb$city))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(city)) %>% 
  group_by(affiliation) %>% 
  mutate(nmatches = sum(!is.na(city))) %>% 
  filter((nmatches > 0 & !is.na(city)) | (nmatches == 0 & row_number() == 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  left_join(dfb, by = "city") %>% 
  mutate(country_match = str_detect(affiliation, country))

# A tibble: 12 x 5
   affiliation              city   nmatches country country_match
   <chr>                    <chr>     <int> <chr>   <lgl>        
 1 DEPARTMENT OF PHARMACY,… AMSTE…        1 NETHER… TRUE         
 2 DEPARTMENT OF BIOCHEMIS… NA            0 NA      NA           
 3 DEPARTMENT OF PATHOLOGY… NA            0 NA      NA           
 4 COLLEGE OF EDUCATION FO… BAGHD…        1 IRAQ    FALSE        
 5 DEPARTMENT OF CLINICAL … BEIJI…        1 CHINA   TRUE         
 6 LABORATORY OF MOLECULAR… NA            0 NA      NA           
 7 BERLIN INSTITUTE OF HEA… BERLIN        1 GERMANY FALSE        
 8 INSTITUTE OF LABORATORY… NA            0 NA      NA           
 9 DEPARTMENT OF CLINICAL … BANGK…        1 THAILA… TRUE         
10 DEPARTMENT OF BIOLOGY, … NA            0 NA      NA           
11 DEPARTMENT OF MOLECULAR… NA            0 NA      NA           
12 LABORATORY OF CARDIOVAS… BEIJI…        1 CHINA   TRUE
```

You could then double-check cases with 1 `nmatches` but `country_match == F`, and when there are 2 or more `nmatches` you can keep the one with `country_match == T`.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy, it works well. The 'nmatches' column is very useful (see my comment to phiver above).

Comment: I elaborated a little on how you might avoid some manual cleaning.

Answer (score 4):

A combination of `str_extract` and either a join or another `str_extract` is one option to get you there.
`str_extract` will get the first value it encounters, with a `paste0` to collapse the cities into a long `or` string to check against.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dfa %>% 
  mutate(city = str_extract(dfa$affiliation, paste0("\\b", dfb$city, collapse = "\\b|"))) %>% 
  left_join(dfb, by = "city")
```

**Edit**: added word bounderies in the `paste0` so that only whole city names are matched and partial matching is avoided.

```
    affiliation      city     country
1      DEPARTMENT OF PHARMACY, AMSTERDAM UNIVERSITY, AMSTERDAM, THE NETHERLANDS AMSTERDAM NETHERLANDS
2  DEPARTMENT OF BIOCHEMISTRY, LADY HARDINGE MEDICAL COLLEGE, NEW DELHI, INDIA.      <NA>        <NA>
3      DEPARTMENT OF PATHOLOGY, CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL, LOS ANGELES, UNITED STATES      <NA>        <NA>
4                 COLLEGE OF EDUCATION FOR PURE SCIENCE, UNIVERSITY OF BAGHDAD.   BAGHDAD        IRAQ
5  DEPARTMENT OF CLINICAL LABORATORY, BEIJING GENERAL HOSPITAL, BEIJING, CHINA.   BEIJING       CHINA
6           LABORATORY OF MOLECULAR BIOLOGY, ISTITUTO ORTOPEDICO, MILAN, ITALY.      <NA>        <NA>
7                 DEPARTMENT OF AGRICULTURE, BERLIN INSTITUTE OF HEALTH, BERLIN    BERLIN     GERMANY
8       INSTITUTE OF LABORATORY MEDICINE, UNIVERSITY HOSPITAL, MUNICH, GERMANY.      <NA>        <NA>
9      DEPARTMENT OF CLINICAL PATHOLOGY, MAHIDOL UNIVERSITY, BANGKOK, THAILAND.   BANGKOK    THAILAND
10                       DEPARTMENT OF BIOLOGY, WASEDA UNIVERSITY, TOKYO, JAPAN      <NA>        <NA>
11           DEPARTMENT OF MOLECULAR BIOLOGY, MINISTRY OF HEALTH, TEHRAN, IRAN.      <NA>        <NA>
12        LABORATORY OF CARDIOVASCULAR DISEASE, FUWAI HOSPITAL, BEIJING, CHINA.   BEIJING       CHINA
```

Comment: Thanks+++ phiver, it works well. However, there is a limit that you could not anticipate since I did not specify it: please read the NB in the above updated question.

Comment: @demon, is your data like this, or does the affiliate line for "BERLIN INSTITUTE OF HEALTH, BERLIN", more like this: "BERLIN INSTITUTE OF HEALTH, , ,BERLIN, "? Because having the missing comma's available would make it a lot easier, because you could use tidyr::separate, instead of looking for matches.

Comment: unfortunately no, the affiliation are like "BERLIN INSTITUTE OF HEALTH, BERLIN". It seems possible to match any word using "\w" in str_exact but I don't how to include this way in your code (https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html). Thanks to you.

Comment: @demon, see adjusted answer.

Comment: Many thanks phiver, it's very useful. I applied your code on a big 'dfa' dataframe (thousands affiliations) crossed with a big 'dfb' (thousands cities) and it works well. The only limit that cannot be avoided is where there are many countries for a same city (e.g. HAMILTON, which is a city of CANADA, NEW ZEALAND, US and UK). Fortunately, thanks to the Andy Eggers's code below, in these cases, rows are duplicated so that all possibilities are provided, which allows to filter out duplicate lines based on other criteria, and manually eliminate those that are not appropriate.